# Adobe Analytics visitorID overwriting with s_vi value

Tags: tags, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

I need to put the default "s_vi" cookie value (for ex:  **[CS]v1|2B54ED85051D673D-400019096000016D[CE]**) into the **s.visitorID** variable, in a cross-domain tracking scenario.

Unfortunately, seems this var does not accept hyphen ("-") values, and the "s_vi" one is including it.

This was my reference: https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/visitorID.html

How achieving this overwriting so?

Thanks